# "Loading services" hangs when trying to set the AutoSave on an Excel workbook

Tags: ms-office

When I enabled AutoSave via a slider on the upper-left of the workbook a dialog pops up and then hangs on *Loading services...* :

[image]

What might be wrong and what is a remedy?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have OneDrive as it's needed for AutoSave. From [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/f1/topic/how-do-i-turn-on-autosave-dbd19b49-ff3a-48f5-8294-671e33a6712c?NS=MACEXCEL&Version=90):

> AutoSave only applies to Office files stored in OneDrive, but the Office AutoRecover feature is on by default and saves your work every 10 minutes.

More specifically from [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/f1/topic/what-is-autosave-6d6bd723-ebfd-4e40-b5f6-ae6e8088f7a5?NS=MACEXCEL&Version=90):

> AutoSave is enabled when working on a file that is saved to OneDrive, OneDrive for Business, or SharePoint Online. If the file is hasn't been saved, or is saved to another location, then AutoSave is disabled.

AutoSave is also disabled when you have OneDrive/Sharepoint but your file is in an older format like .xls, or your file is in a local OneDrive folder and OneDrive synchronization is paused etc.

If you have AutoSave enabled i.e. above mentioned requirement are met then it may still not work. The workbook may contain unsupported features. In such a situation [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/f1/topic/what-is-autosave-6d6bd723-ebfd-4e40-b5f6-ae6e8088f7a5?NS=MACEXCEL&Version=90) suggest of doing one or more of the following to (try) enable it:

- Turn off the Shared Workbook feature. This feature has been replaced by co-authoring.
- If possible, remove password encryption from the file: Go to File > Info > Protect Workbook. Delete the password and click OK.
- If possible, remove restricted access: Go to File > Info > Protect Workbook > Restrict Access and click Unrestricted Access.
- If you are opening a workbook snapshot from SharePoint, open the file instead of the snapshot.
- Turn off Refresh data when opening file setting on all tables and PivotTables in the file. Select the table or PivotTable, then go to Table Tools Design > Refresh > Connection Properties. Then uncheck Refresh data when opening file.
- Inactivate an add-in that's causing AutoSave to be disabled. Select File > Options > Add-Ins > Excel Add-ins > Go and then clear the check box for the add-in.

If you don't have OneDrive then I suggest to look at AutoRecovery, maybe it suits your needs: [Recover files in Office for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/f1/topic/6c6425b1-6559-4bbf-8f80-4f038402ff02?showContactUsNav=False&ns=MACEXCEL&version=90)

Comment: I don't have any of those special features.   I LOST MY WORK when the system was rebooted so I don't know what's going on with _AutoRecover_ .  It does not work on this computer.

Comment: There is detailed information how to access autorecover file in link provided above. Autorecover is on by default so if you haven't turned it off manually there should be maximum of 10 minutes of work lost.